# Get number of days between two NSDates when crossing new year

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I need to get the number of days between two dates which I get but if I input **for example**: 2016-12-10 and 2017-01-10 there will be a negative number of days. This is just occur when it´s new year between those two dates.

```
//Get the number of days between two NSDates
func daysBetween(date: NSDate) -> Int {
    let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let date1 = calendar.startOfDayForDate(self)
    let date2 = calendar.startOfDayForDate(date)
    let components = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: date1, toDate: date2, options: [])
    return components.day
}

//Using the function
let daysBetween = fromDate.daysBetween(toDate)

//Printing -334 if new year is between fromDate and toDate
print(daysBetween)
```

How can I modify my daysBetween(date: NSDate) function to prevent this from happening?

**Edit:**
Please don´t pay attention to why it´s printing exacltly -334. That´s just because fromDate and toDate are different days in month. The problem a wanna solve is why the response is negative and not 31 as it should be.

**Solved:**
It turned out to be as many of you thought. The fromDate is greater then toDate and causing a negative number. Stupid mistake. Thx guys!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. With your input data, the result is `31`.

Comment: Can you provide a (small) *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I'd suggest confirming that the two dates are what you think they are. For example, if rather than `2016-12-10`, if that first date was `2017-12-10`, you'd get your `-334`.

Answer (score 1):

You not need to worry about the days going negative. It's better to know if the first date (for example selected from an input `UIDatePicker`) is bigger than another. That is handled automatically when you converted back to an `NSDate`. 
If the problem is how to print the days , you can use `abs(days)`.

Answer (score 0):

First compare both dates and then you can get correct positive value

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-12-10")!
let endDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2017-01-10")!

let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let dayUnit: NSCalendarUnit = .Day
if startDate.compare(endDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending{
   let components = cal.components(dayUnit, fromDate: endDate, toDate: startDate, options: [])
   print(components)
} else {
   let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])
   print(components)
}
```

As Describe by **Leo Dabus**

You can do it without comparing the dates also:

```
let com = cal.components(dayUnit, fromDate: startDate.earlierDate(endDate), toDate: startDate.laterDate(endDate), options: [])
print(com)
```

Comment: But this does not explain the output of `-334` days between 2016-12-10 and 2017-01-10. The difference would be either `31` or `-31`, depending on the order of the dates.

Comment: NSDate has a method called earlierDate `cal.components(dayUnit, fromDate: startDate.earlierDate(endDate), toDate: startDate.laterDate(endDate), options: [])`

Comment: @MartinR Yes i'm also not geeting any idea about -334. According to question i think  OP wants positive difference between 2 dates as new year is there so i have posted this answer.

Comment: But  2017-01-10 is later than 2016-12-10, so comparing the dates does not make any difference. There must be another problem ...

Comment: @MartinR yes it could be possible, may be some other issue OP have

Comment: @Rob Yes by taking date 2017-12-10 instead of 2016-12-10 results -334